# Concrete5 5.7: using a ServiceProvider cross-package

Tags: php, concrete5, concrete5-5.7

I'm migrating old code to 5.7, and I'm running into a weird issue when it comes to helpers. I'm working with two packages - let's call them A and B. Package A one implements a ServiceProvider. I would like to use it in a controller in package B, but it seems unable to find it properly. I'm configuring it in the `install()` function of package A, as follows

```
$providers = Config::get('providers');
if (!$providers) {
    $providers = array('group_membership' => '\Concrete\Package\A\Src\GroupMembership\GroupMembershipProvider');
} else {
    $providers['group_membership'] = '\Concrete\Package\A\Src\GroupMembership\GroupMembershipProvider';
}
Config::set('providers', $providers);
```

And in the ServiceProvider itself, I bind it accordingly;

```
<?php namespace Concrete\Package\A\Src\GroupMembership;

use \Concrete\Core\Foundation\Service\Provider as ServiceProvider;

class GroupMembershipProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register() {
        $this->app->bind('helper/group_membership', 'Concrete\Package\A\Src\GroupMembership\GroupMembershipProvider');
    }
}
```

Then when I want to use in package A, this works just fine:

```
$helper = Core::make('helper/group_membership');
```

But when I do that in package B, it tells me:

```
Class helper/group_membership does not exist
```

What could I do, except for merging the two packages together? What may be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providers cannot be registered like that since [we consume that config entry](https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5-5.7.0/blob/develop/web/concrete/bootstrap/start.php#L141-142) way before [we load packages](https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5-5.7.0/blob/develop/web/concrete/bootstrap/start.php#L258-L263).

The proper way to register a package is to instantiate a new `\Concrete\Core\Foundation\Service\ProviderList` and use the `registerProvider` method.

[Here's a good example for how to do that](https://github.com/Buttress/addon_legacy_package_concepts/blob/master/packages/legacy_sample/controller.php#L43-L45)

```php
// Register our service provider
$list = new ProviderList(\Core::getFacadeRoot());
$list->registerProvider('Concrete\\Package\\LegacySample\\Libraries\\ServiceProvider');
```

Comment: Nice! Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: So is the concrete5 documentation site going to link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask now?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, I'm not working on the official documentation. We are however going to start funneling developer discussion to stackoverflow.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make sure these kind of things get documented somewhere centrally rather than scattered through the codebase and (now) stackoverflow?

Comment: Yes, cool story. I'm a developer not the boss, I am just here answering your question. If you have questions about the concrete5 documentation I'd suggest posting in the forums where a person that actually makes those decision can see it.