# Concrete5 (5.7.5.6) How to register package service provider the whole application?

Tags: php, service-provider, concrete5-5.7

If I use provider located from the application source it works:

app.php:

```
return array(
    'providers' => append_config(array(
        '\Application\Src\Utility\UtilityServiceProvider',
    ))
);
```

but if I try to register a provider located from a package, just got "not found" error

```
return array(
    'providers' => append_config(array(
        '\Application\Src\Utility\UtilityServiceProvider',
        '\Concrete\Package\MyPackage\Src\Utility\MyPackageServiceProvider',
    ))
);
```

The `MyPackageServiceProvider` inside the package works well.

Of course, if I register manually ex. in the PageTypeController:

```
$app = Core::make('app');
$provider = new \Concrete\Package\MyPackage\Src\Utility\MyPackageServiceProvider($app);
$provider->register();
```

it also work, but I don't want to register all of controller outside the package, if possible.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111552/register-a-package-service-provider-from-within-that-package), but it's not Laravel and not help me.

Thank you

Comment: Did you see this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965533/concrete5-5-7-using-a-serviceprovider-cross-package?rq=1 maybe it helps